# Is it safe to connect lithium protection circuit to positive terminal of the battery?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, protection

I'm designing a lithium battery powered circuit, and want to include a battery protection circuit (e.g. DW01, but the question is applicable to other chips as well). All example circuits I can find on the internet place the control MOSFETs at the negative terminal of the battery. However, I want to have them at the positive terminal of the battery. I can't think of any reason why this wouldn't work, but I also can't find any reference on the internet showing it done this way, so I am afraid there is something I didn't think of. Usually I'd just try it out, but I don't really feel like blowing up a lithium battery ;)

To be clear, the (badly paint-modified) circuit I want to use looks something like this:

[image: Circuit]

Comment: And what was the reference circuit before you modified it and where on the net did it come from?

Comment: @Andyaka The original for this circuit is the typical application circuit from the [DW01 datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/2/5/1/DW01-P_DataSheet_V10.pdf). But other battery protection IC's such as the S-8261 or BQ2970 have similar reference circuits in their datasheets.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @BruceAbbott It allows the negative terminal of the battery to be connected to the common ground, which allows me to save a pin in the power connector. There's a load sharing circuit further on to support both battery power and externally supplied power from two separate pins on the positive rails already. No big deal, but would be nice to have.

Comment: The protection circuit should be mounted on the battery itself, and then it doesn't matter which terminal is 'common'. If it has to be in a holder then that should be connect directly to the PCM, with system ground on the 'BATT-' terminal. For full protection, nothing else should be connected directly to the battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original circuit in the DW01 data sheet is this: -

[image]

And the biggest problem with your circuit is that when putting N channel MOSFETs in the positive rail, you won't be able to turn them on from the control signals OD and OC. Those signals in the normal circuit (immediately above) will rise positive above BATT- and activate M1 or M2. To activate either of those MOSFETs in your new circuit, the drive levels have to rise higher in voltage than BATT+ (by probably at least 2 volts if not more) and there is no facility in the DW01 chip to achieve this.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Thanks!